# Como pegar a hora atual e diminuir 24 horas dela?

Tags: javascript

Como fazer para pegar a data atual em JavaScript, e criar uma outra data, só que 24 horas antes?

Para pegar a hora atual é só fazer:
`var data = new Date();` para pegar 24 horas antes, como faz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes usar o `.setDate` e passar um dia a menos da data atual, assim ele vai mudar a data interna dessa variável para o que queres:

```js
var data = new Date();
data.setDate(data.getDate() - 1);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Answer (score 1):

Diminua a data atual pela quantidade de milissegundos em 24h.

```js
var date = (new Date () - ((24*60*60)*1000));
    console.log(new Date(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Através da função getDate() do objeto Date consegue se capturar o dia

```js
data = new Date();//cria o objeto
dia = data.getDate();//recupera o dia atual 

console.log(dia)
```

assim é positivável manipular a variável dia como quiser.